# How to use own copy of static library in each shared library

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, linker

I have some static library that I can't change or rebuild. The library uses global variables. Something like this:

```
//lib A
#include <iostream>

static int i = 0;

void printA(){
    std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
}
```

I want to create two shared libraries that have their own "copy" of static library and its global state:

```
//lib B
#include "liba.h"

void printB(){
    printA();
}
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

```
//lib C
#include "liba.h"

void printC(){
    printA();
}
```

... and use them simultaneously:

```
#include "libb.h"
#include "libc.h"

int main(){
    printB();
    printB();
    printC();
    printC();
}
```

I expect following output:

```
0
1
0
1
```

.. but actually get:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Seems like `libB` and `libC` share common counter variable. If had access to `libA` source code, I would rebuild it with `-fvisibility=hidden`. But unfortunately I have only binary.

Is there any way to achieve expected behavior without `libA` rebuilding?

Comment: `If had access to` `I have only binary.`  - so you have access `libA.a` or not? You can unpack `libA.a` to `.o` files, then rename _all_ symbols using ex. `objcopy --redefine-sym printA=printAcopy`, then rebuild `libAcopy.a` then from `printC()`  call `printAcopy` - `printC() { printAcopy(); }`.

Comment: Put your copy of the library in a separate namespace. Or, build a wrapper shared object around the static lib. The wrapper makes all symbols private, and only exports functions of interest with a different name.

Comment: Are the two libraries linked separately?

Comment: @KamilCuk, Yes, I have `libA.a`, but I'd rather not change it. Because it may be updated once.

Comment: @jww, `Put your copy of the library in a separate namespace` - what do you mean by that? `The wrapper makes all symbols private` - are you sure? `libA` and `libB` are inherently shared wrappers, but it share common state. Or I got it wrong?

Comment: @JL2210, yes. Two separated shared libraries with common "root"

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with "Linux"? Because the behavior of shared libraries differs between Linux and Windows. Under Windows, a shared library (dll) will have its own version of those globals, just as the OP expects.

Answer (score 3):

If LibA uses a static counter which libB and libC increment by calling `printA`, then there's no way to do what you want without object file manipulation or non-portable hacks.

The linker resolves all references to global variables (even `static`s) to the same symbol at link time.

If you're willing to manipulate object files, then the following should work for you:

```
$ objcopy --prefix-symbols=copy_ liba.a liba-copy.a
```

---

```
#define printA copy_ printA
#include "liba.h"
/* ... */
```

If you can get the symbols from the static library using `nm` (the name you'll be looking for will be in the form of `<counter name>.<process ID>`) and you do something like the following, then you can read and write the static counter variable at runtime:

```
int counter asm("<counter name>.<process ID>");
counter = 0;
```

Note that this process will have to be repeated after every update of the library.

Comment: you don't need `ar x` just `objcopy --prefix-symbols=copy_ liba.a liba-copy.a` There is however a real problem, because the names are mangled.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the static library and rename all symbols that use the global state.  Because the symbols are compiled with c++, you are out of luck, the symbols are mangled.

You can write a C interface for all the accesses and recompile the static library hiding it's symbols and then use some `objcopy --prefix-symbols` or`g++ -Wl,--wrap=printA` to prefix/rename the C symbols.

Or you need to know beforehand the already mangled C++ names, and then call `objcopy --redefine-sym _Z6printAv=_Z10printAcopyv` etc. for each symbol the library exports.

Below is the test setup that calls the `objcopy` on the mangled names. I found out the symbol names by inspecting the object files, `nm a.o` and `nm c.o`. Here it is:

```
cat <<EOF >Makefile
all: liba.a b.o main.o  c.o
    # we have access only to liba.a only
    objcopy --redefine-sym _Z6printAv=_Z10printAcopyv liba.a libacopy.a
    g++ main.o b.o c.o liba.a libacopy.a -o a.out
    ./a.out

liba.a: a.o
    ar rcs liba.a a.o

clean:  
    rm -fr *.o *.a *.out tmp

EOF

cat <<EOF >a.cpp
#include <iostream>

static int i = 0;

void printA(){
    std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
}
EOF

cat <<EOF >b.cpp
void printA();
void printB(){
    printA();
}
EOF

cat <<EOF >c.cpp
void printAcopy();
void printC(){
    printAcopy();
}
EOF

cat <<EOF >main.cpp
void printB();
void printC();
int main(){
    printB();
    printB();
    printC();
    printC();
}
EOF
```

You can compile with `make` and run:

```
g++    -c -o a.o a.cpp
ar rcs liba.a a.o
g++    -c -o b.o b.cpp
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++    -c -o c.o c.cpp
# we have access only to liba.a only
objcopy --redefine-sym _Z6printAv=_Z10printAcopyv liba.a libacopy.a
g++ main.o b.o c.o liba.a libacopy.a -o a.out
./a.out
0
1
0
1
```

Comment: Makefiles don't work unless they have tabs. 8 spaces don't work.

Comment: Steckoverflow messes up with formatting, just `sed 's/^[[:space:]]\+/\t/'` it ; )

Comment: Perhaps you should add that to your answer.